# javascript not work

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, smarty

I have this scripts in the begin of code:

```
 <!--rest--> 
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/ajaxmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/last.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/fancydropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <!--end rest-->

    <!--fancybox-->

     <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/fancy/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/fancy/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <!--end fancybox-->
```

all script included in 'rest' work perfectly, but fancybox don't work. if i comment the 'rest' scripts, fancybox work.I put this script between 'end rest' and fancybox, and alert not appear.

..............................

```
    <!--end rest-->
        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                            alert("Hello!");
                            });
        </script>
     <!--fancybox-->

     <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/fancy/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"                     type="text/javascript">
     </script>
```

..........................

What are the possible problems for which scripts do not work together?

Comment: fancybox depends on jquery, does it not? You're loading it before jquery, so probably it's failing somehow for lack of jquery.

Comment: Please change your question's title to something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

You're including jquery twice. Comment out the one in the `fancy` directory and I bet fancybox will work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have to move your jquery plugins/dependencies after you load jquery. Like so:

```
 <script src="{base_url()}assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!--end fancybox-->
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert("Hello!");
     });
 </script>
 <!--rest-->
```